# How to filter a string to a list on Python

Tags: python, string, list

I want to filter a string like this : 'Hello%World' ----> List = ['Hello','World'] Is there any built-in function for this?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `str.split`:

```
>>> strs='Hello%World'
>>> strs.split("%")
['Hello', 'World']
```

**help(str.split)**:

> S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the delimiter string. 
>   If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If sep is not
>   specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and empty
>   strings are removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

simply split

```
str ='Hello%World'
print str.split("%")
```

gives you

```
>>> 
['Hello', 'World']
```

Comment: How's that different from my answer? And don't use `str` as a variable name.